# Magento2 - How to include introjs?

Tags: magento2

I need to show step by step guide.

I have checked for this and found introjs

https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/

How to use this for demo purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty well documented in the magento dev docs:
https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-javascript-module/

I would advise to add it into a separate "lib" folder.

If you don't know how to code: I know one magento shop which has this feature: all demo pages of the extension seller Amasty. There is an extension amasty_tips which adds this feature. Maybe they sell it to you.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider [GuideChimp](https://github.com/Labs64/GuideChimp) - well done and maintained library to create guided product tours.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to [create a module](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/) for Intro.js to live in.

From there CloudySi is correct that you will want to make a Javascript module but there are some details that are not covered in the link posted.

Inside your module you will need a `requirejs-config.js` file that will "register" for lack of a better term the javascript. This points to the files we will be creating and makes them available to Magento.

> app/code/IntroJs/Tutorial/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'introJs': 'IntroJs_Tutorial/js/lib/intro',
            'tester': 'IntroJs_Tutorial/js/tester'
        }
    }
};
```

You then need to download Intro.js and place it where we have defined in the `requirejs-config.js`:

> app/code/IntroJs/Tutorial/view/frontend/web/js/lib/intro.js

You will also need to place the css file as well:

> app/code/IntroJs/Tutorial/view/frontend/web/css/source/lib/_introjs.less

We need to call this file in the Magento way, so we need to make a `_module.less` and call the lib css in it. We can save a step by copy and pasting the IntroJS css into this file, but this is more extendable if you have some custom css that you need to use.

> src/app/code/IntroJs/Tutorial/view/frontend/web/css/source/_module.less

```
@import 'lib/_introjs.less';
```

We can then create the file we need to defining our functions:

> app/code/IntroJs/Tutorial/view/frontend/web/js/tester.js

```
define([
        "jquery",
        "introJs"
    ], function($, introJs){
        "use strict";
        return function(config, element) {
            $(document).on("click", ".tut-button", function() {
                introJs().start();
            });
        }
    }
);
```

So there are a few things to note in this file. Because we registered our IntroJs lib file, we now have access to it in any Javascript file with `"introJs"` in the file's `define`. From there it gets passed into the function with `function($, introJs)` so we can use it. I have called this `introJs` to match the lib API, but this name is up to you, i made it this way to make using the lib easier.

Once in the return, we use a click action to attach to a button (which we haven't created yet) and then start the intro with `introJs().start();`

We need a XML file to display our template:

> app/code/IntroJs/Tutorial/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="IntroJs_Tutorial::tester.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And then we have our template file:

> app/code/IntroJs/Tutorial/view/frontend/templates/tester.phtml

```
<div class="tester" data-mage-init='{"tester":{}}'>
    <div>
        <h1 data-step="1" data-intro="This is a tooltip!">Basic Usage</h1>
        <p class="lead" data-step="4" data-intro="Another step.">This is the basic usage of IntroJs</p>
        <a class="csos-tut-button" href="javascript:void(0);">Show me how</a>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-sm-6" data-step="2" data-intro="Ok, wasn't that fun?" data-position='right' data-scrollTo='tooltip'>
            <h4>Section One</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ad amet commodi dolore eius inventore, magnam magni minima molestiae, non qui recusandae tempora. error eum, facere id illo illum, iure nobis quaerat qui ratione rem repellat repudiandae sed sint ullam?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" data-step="3" data-intro="More features, more fun."  data-position='left'>
            <h4>Section Two</h4>
            <p>Aliquid at corporis deserunt, dolore doloribus eos error expedita explicabo fugiat, incidunt inventore iusto laudantium nulla officiis pariatur ratione repudiandae saepe. Commodi deserunt exercitationem in odit, rem similique vitae. similique sunt ullam veniam voluptatem voluptatum.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's important to note the points that are required to make this work. First we have the `data-mage-init='{"tester":{}}'` which is creating the scope for our Javascript file. We have the `class="tut-button"` which is what we are targeting with jQuery in our JS file. And then you have the IntroJs API in the file that connects everything together `data-step="1" data-intro="This is a tooltip!"`. Play around with these till you get a result you are looking for.

Hope this helps.